# How to compile TOR into DLL

Tags: tor-install

I wish to compile TOR into DLL, so that I can include it in C# project. I will then use pInvoke to start it.

Currently to compile I use following steps, but it builds tor.EXE

1. Type "tar zxf tor- 0.3.1.9.tar.gz "
2. cd tor- 0.3.1.9
3. Type "./configure --disable-gcc-hardening  --enable-static-libevent  --enable-static-openssl  --enable-static-zlib  --with-libevent-dir=../libevent-2.0.21-stable/   --with-openssl-dir=../openssl-1.0.1h/   --with-zlib-dir=../zlib-1.2.8/"
4. Type "make"

So can anyone guide me, how can I compile TOR into DLL ?

Regards

Comment: https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/or/tor_api.h newish and experimental feature.

Comment: The first step is still to get Tor compiled as a DLL, though.